# This task requires that the user account specified has Log on as batch job rights

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler, application

I have created a basic task under our windows server 2008 r2 Task Scheduler.but when I try saving the task I got the following error:-

```
This task requires that the user account specified has Log on as batch job rights.
```

now I am not sure if this right is part of the user permission defined inside active directory.. or this is a permission that I need to define separately on the local windows VM ?? can anyone advice on this please?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Task Scheduler : Logon as Batch Job Rights](https://serverfault.com/questions/138817/task-scheduler-logon-as-batch-job-rights)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a user right that's applicable to the local system. You can grant the right locally or define it in a GPO that applies to the system in question.

Comment: now what I did is that inside the local vm I opened secpol.msc and I define the user under the "local policy >> User Rights Assignment>>Log on as a Batch job" and now the user is able to run scheduled jobs.. so is this a valid approach ? I though this permission will be part of the user active directory profile..

Comment: That is a valid approach and no, it's not part of a user's profile or AD account.

Comment: I found @deadlydog's answer to be more useful. https://serverfault.com/a/1021089/121200

Answer (score 18):

Had the same issue today. I added the user to:

> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a batch job

But was still getting the error. I found [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/760ee186-8074-40a5-95b0-35d17c2bdfab/log-on-as-batch-job-right?forum=winserverGP), and it turns out there's also this setting that I had to remove the user from (not sure how it got in there):

> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Deny log on as a batch job

Comment: This is a great answer. In case you got here trying to setup a task on your windows home edition - remember you're not going to find the local security policy on it. The group policy editor is only available on the pro version

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to my having a local user and a domain user with the same username, and trying to create the windows task with the wrong user.  One had the rights described in the other answers (GPO, Admin Tools), and one did not.